# XSLT variable not recognized

Tags: xml, visual-studio-code, xslt

I've worked with XSLT variables before, but for some reason, I can not get the stylesheet to see an assigned variable.  When I copy sample code it seems to work, so it has to be something I'm doing wrong.  Below is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/JDF">
    <xsl:variable name="customer" 
        select="/JDF/ResourcePool[1]/CustomerInfo[1]/@CustomerID"/>
            <job>
                <jobInfo>$customer</jobInfo>
            </job>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the above the result is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
   <jobInfo>$customer</jobInfo>
</job>
```

Comment: The sample code I'm referring to is just an example off of W3Schools.

Comment: Just a note because of the [visual-studio-code] tag - if you were using the XSLT/XPath extension you would get the following warning signs:
1. The  'customer' name in the xsl:variable extension would be grayed out (because it's unused)
2. $customer would have improper syntax-highlighting for a variable reference
3. you would get no XPath auto-complete within the 'jobInfo' element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### XSLT 1.0, 2.0

Change

```
<jobInfo>$customer</jobInfo>
```

to

```
<jobInfo>
  <xsl:value-of select="$customer"/>
</jobInfo>
```

### XSLT 3.0+

If [text value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#text-value-templates) are enabled (using, for example `xsl:stylesheet/@expand-text="yes"`), then you could use:

```
<jobInfo>{$customer}</jobInfo>
```

Comment: Thank You!  I feel like a moron!

Comment: You're welcome.  Evaluation contexts can be hard to keep track of -- it's a natural mistake.